# "Covering letter" vs "cover letter"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage, business-language

I am more accustomed to seeing the term "cover letter". But one company I'm looking at now says "covering letter".

Is there a difference? (Perhaps British vs American?)

Comment: In the U.S., we use "cover letter", at least that's been my experience. I haven't heard anyone one use "covering letter" in I don't know how long, if ever (and I'm talking decades). Good candidate for Google Ngrams.

Comment: @RichardKayser  Likewise and vice-versa in the UK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ODO, [***covering letter***](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/covering-letter) is used in UK English, and [***cover letter***](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cover-letter) in US English. They mean the exact same thing.

According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cover%20letter%2Ccovering%20letter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccover%20letter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccovering%20letter%3B%2Cc0), since the 1980s, *covering letter* is in a steady decline, while *cover letter* has become the most popular one.

[image: Google Ngram]

According to [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=cover%20letter,covering%20letter), *cover letter* is the most popular one.

[image: Google Trends]

Comment: You pretty much covered it!